# Radio buttons selected go to URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to use the value of the selected radio button to go to a specific URL.  Currently the Javascript I am using to do so is choosing the first "id" of the inputs and not using the value of what is actually selected.

**HTML**

```
<form action="https://www.neurodimension.net/solo/products/Cart.aspx" method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="changeActionURL();">
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1025" />NeuroSolutions Pro<br />
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1024" />NeuroSolutions<br />
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1026" />NeuroSolutions Student
         <input type="submit" />    
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeActionURL() {
var forma = document.getElementById('myForm');
forma.action += "?action=add&actiondata0=" + document.getElementById('ns_license').value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ID's that are the same, which is bad! `getElementById` expects one result, and it gets one by taking the first element which has that ID (ignoring your other 2, as it should). Use the `class` attribute on similar elements.

```
    <input type="radio" name="ns_license" class="ns_license" value="1025" />NeuroSolutions Pro<br />
     <input type="radio" name="ns_license" class="ns_license" value="1024" />NeuroSolutions<br />
     <input type="radio" name="ns_license" class="ns_license" value="1026" />NeuroSolutions Student
```

And to get the checked element

```
var checkedElem = document.querySelector(".ns_license:checked");
```

And if `querySelector` is out of the question:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("ns_license"),
    checkedIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].checked)
        checkedIndex = i;
}
```

Your current checked element would be at `elems[checkedIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

to change a a specific attribute of an element, you can use the

> setAttribute()

function of javascript. that should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

While `querySelector` will work for modern browsers it does not work for IE <=7

If you want you can traverse through the `radios by name`, then check if the value is checked. If it is then return that value. That is the use of the `getRadioValue()` function:

```
<form action="https://www.neurodimension.net/solo/products/Cart.aspx" method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="changeActionURL();">
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1025" />NeuroSolutions Pro<br />
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1024" />NeuroSolutions<br />
         <input type="radio" name="ns_license" id="ns_license" value="1026" />NeuroSolutions Student
         <input type="submit" />    
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeActionURL() {
    var forma = document.getElementById('myForm');
    forma.action += "?action=add&actiondata0=" + getRadioValue('ns_license');
}

function getRadioValue(name){
    var rads = document.getElementsByName('ns_license');
    for(var x=0; x<rads.length;x++){
        if(rads[x].checked){
            return rads[x].value;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```